# Pass string from Java to Java script function

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Am, quite new to Phone gap and Java script. If any one provide with sample or sugesstion thats would helps a lot.

Exception : I got following exception : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getName'

```
public class ViewerActivity extends DroidGap {
    private CordovaActivity mGap;
    private WebView mWebView;

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       mWebView=new WebView(this);
       mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterfaceClass (), "jsinterface");
       mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/sample.html");
    }


}
```

Java Script Interface class:

```
public class JavaScriptInterfaceClass {
    public WebView mAppView;
    public DroidGap mGap;


public JavaScriptInterfaceClass(DroidGap gap, WebView view) {
    this.mAppView = view;
    this.mGap = gap;

}

public String getName() {


  return "android";
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-js/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
    <script src="css-js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css-js/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var name = jsinterface.getName();
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!"+name);
    }
    </script>
 <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Class name is wrong. The correct one should be

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterfaceClass(), "jsinterface");
                                                       ^
```

Comment: Hi Ling I tried with this also, but unfortunately, same error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getName'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the change in Class name in ling's answer, you must put one line in front of the function.

@Javascriptinterface
public String getName() {
(...)
}

This prevents malicious js code from just dialing up any function that may happen to exist